# How to block a URL to load and then present a HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to intercept some user requests, cancel it and then present a hand made HTML.

First I tried to call `window.stop()` in the beginning of content.js, but after checking the Network tab of the Developer Tool I noticed that some elements are still being requested (although not loaded, it seems).

Then I tried to add a `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` listener inside background.js. So inside the callback I set my hand made HTML (`document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = myHtml`) and in the end I canceled the original request (`return {cancel: true}`), but, although the original request is being canceled, my HTML doesn't appear.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:firefox-addon] if you are using Chrome specific APIs?

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page which is not related to web pages so modifying its html won't do you no good. You can use webRequest API to redirect to a data:text/html URL with your html embedded in it.

Comment: @Quentin, in order to make it run on Firefox the only difference is calling `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, instead of `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`. This subtle difference is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, but I see issues in your solution. First it doesn't seem to support complex HTMLs. Also, I don't want to change the visible URL in the address bar.

Comment: Any complexity is supported in a data URI so it's not a problem, but if you want to keep the same address, you'll have to 1) keep using window.stop() inside the content script, 2) move your innerHTML assignment in the content script, 3) cancel all sub-resources within that tab id using onBeforeRequest.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I'm already using `run_at": "document_start`. I noticed that the bigger content.js is and the further inside it I call `window.load()` the more requests can be made by the original page. It seems while content.js is processed the original page continues to load. Unfortunately I have to do a bunch of things inside content.js before calling `window.stop()`, so some undesired requests are made. :(